# Add a space in a angular expression

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i need to add another space between my word and my angular bind. Here my code:

```
<button class="button button-clear comp back" href="#">
     Comparto {{titolo}}
</button>
```

I tried with Comparto  {{titolo}}, {{ titolo}}, {{ " " + titolo}}, {{ "\s" + titolo}} but all this method don't work :( how can i add this space?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;`

Like this:

```
<button class="button button-clear comp back" href="#">
     Comparto&nbsp;{{titolo}}
</button>
```

Read [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&nbsp;` to add space in html.

```
<button class="button button-clear comp back" href="https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36567991/edit">
 Comparto&nbsp; {{titolo}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class="button button-clear comp back" href="#">
     <p>Comparto {{titolo}}</p>
</button>
```

Paragraph tags will save the day :)

Answer (score 1):

we can achieve using `<pre>` tag also

```
<button class="button button-clear comp back"> 
<pre style="margin:0px;">Comparto   <span>{{titolo}}</span> </pre></button>
```